# Disable app downloads by devices with physical keyboards

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-emulator, android-manifest

I have an android app that disables the use of soft keyboard, as it has it's own soft keyboard for use. However, it is still downloadable by android devices with physical keyboards and they can input into the apps editTexts.
Is there any manifest code I can use to prevent the app being downloaded by such devices with physical keyboards?

Also, I'm going to make a version of the app that will only be used by such devices. Is there any manifest code to make sure it is only downloaded by such devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [uses-configuration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-configuration-element.html) manifest tag. For physical keyboard :

```
<uses-configuration android:reqHardKeyboard="true"/>
```

You can see more examples [here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=3Wi2gwGoZZ0C&pg=PT480&lpg=PT480&dq=uses-configuration%20physical%20keyboard&source=bl&ots=Lcjfm4HdNh&sig=WtcI2kD3ZIsgFF0FgTW9LbcKM2A&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=WfuLVJ-zIOu6ygOh9YCQBw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=uses-configuration%20physical%20keyboard&f=false)